# Simple HTML bar graph generation

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph

I am a c++ Linux guy who is trying to make a bar graph using html or js.
I tried googling on how to generate the bar graph. But couldn't understand it properly.

I have a file (content.txt) with the following content:

```
A - 0
B - 3
C - 1
D - 2
E - 2 
F - 0
```

All the alphabets needs to be represented in Y axis.
The bar color is based on the value in the file. (always the value will be in the range of 0 to 3)

All the four values needs to be represented in different colors.

The graph looks like below.
Please help me out in reading the content.txt file (which dynamically changes its value of A to F within 0 to 3) & represent as a graph.[image]

Comment: After parsing the text file and having data in a variable. You have to choose which tool you will use to draw this graph. As this is very specific and simple, I suggest that you use the Low level solution which is the Canvas element of HTML. Please try to start writing some code then ask a question when you have a specific programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

As described above, the hardest part will be reading the data from the file system. If you could put your data into a JSON blob or an object, it'd be much easier.

Is there any reason you'd want the bar chart to be full on HTML? For simple charts, I highly recommend ChartJS (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart) ...it's very simple to use especially if your data is in JSON / Obj format.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I dont have any constraint that i should use html itself.